# Ambiguous method call in appium WebDriver findElement API

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8, appium

I am using appium 6.1.0 which has `<T extends WebElement> T findElement(By by);` method on `WebDriver` class. Somewhere in automated tests I have following APIs -

```
protected String getText(WebElement element) {
    return getText(element, Config.LOAD_WAIT);
}
```

and

```
protected String getText(By by) {
    return getText(by, Config.LOAD_WAIT);
}
```

And `getText` method is invoked by test as -

```
public String getFullName() {
    return getText(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".basicDataSection)))
}
```

But using `WebDriver` class from `appium` dependency throws exception on `getFullName` method about method call being ambiguous since it matches both `getText(WebElement element)` and `getText(By by)` How is this possible since `findElement` return type is `T extends WebElement` in `WebDriver` class in `appium` dependency?

On a different note, there is also `WebElement findElement(By by);` API in `WebDriver` class in `selenium-api` but after adding `appium` dependency method in my project they have begun to refer to `WebDriver` class from `appium` dependency and not from `selenium-api` dependency. Unfortunately `WebDriver` api in both classes have same package `org.openqa.selenium`. 
I am not sure if `WebDriver` class from `appium` and `selenium-api` can be used interchangeably as they have different automation purpose (i.e. mobile app and web app). If `WebDriver` class from `appium` and `selenium-api` can not be used interchangeably then is there a way to enforce to use `WebDriver` class from `selenium-api` dependency and not from `appium` dependency?

Comment: *is there a way to enforce to use WebDriver class from selenium-api dependency and not from appium dependency*.. look for a way to exclude the class while importing the `appium` dependency..what build 
framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider using [MobileElement](https://static.javadoc.io/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.html) instead of [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to avoid clashes with underlying Selenium API
2. Make sure to have only [appium-java-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0) library in your project dependencies, Appium 6.1.0 assumes [Selenium 3.12.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.12.0) so you have to use exactly this version of Selenium in order to avoid [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) so I would recommend using dependency management solution like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) to automatically resolve Appium Java client library and all its [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). See [Code Examples -> Appium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for comprehensive information and sample projects

Comment: I am using `MobileElement` and `gradle`, though my classes now end up resolving `WebDriver` from `appium` and not `selenium`. I suppose the problem is due to `<T extends WebElement> T findElement(By by)` which I mentioned in my previous message.